# Error: agotado el tamaño de memoria permitido

Tags: php

¿Qué significa este error y cómo puedo resolverlo?

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/tustand/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php on line 1703

No podía entrar a WordPress entonces regresé a PHP 5.4.

Comment: Aparte de aumentar la memoria, deberías revisar si no tienes problemas con algún plugin desactualizado o que está consumiendo demasiada memoria o con código que no está optimizado.

Answer (score 5):

[`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits):

> Establece el máximo de memoria en bytes que un script puede consumir.
>   Ayuda a prevenir que scripts mal programados consuman toda la memoria
>   disponible en el servidor. Observe que para no tener límite de
>   memoria, se ha de establecer esta directiva a -1.

Puedes aumentar los valores en diferentes sitios:

En el fichero `php.ini`:

- `memory_limit = 256M`

En el fichero `.htaccess`:

- `php_value memory_limit 256M`

Con [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php), agregando a tu archivo PHP `memory_limit`:

- `<?php ini_set( 'memory_limit', '256M' ); ?>`

Como estás usando **Wordpress** puedes cambiar ese valor en **`wp-config.php`**:

- `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!